# Facebook Audience Network returns "unknown error" when loading an ad

Tags: android, facebook, error-code, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I'm trying to integrate Facebook native ads in my Android app. Whenever I load an ad with my placement id I get an error code of -1: unknown error inside the `onError` method.

When I try other placement ids it works fine. Does anyone has any clue what could cause an unknown error?

Here is my code:

```
AbstractAdListener adListener = new AbstractAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Failed to load ad from Facebook Audience Network: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Show Ad
        }
}

NativeAd nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, adUnitId);
native.setAdListener(adListener);
native.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the facebook account that is logged in your phone to facebook testers @ dashboard > roles >testers.
And for emulator you have to add test device for the emulator whose id is printed in logcat when you run the app on emulator.

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("your hash key");
```

**EDIT**
For test ads you will have to add the device as test device by the hashkey printed when you run it for the first time.(Both for emulator and phone).

For live ads your app should be live on playstore.After that add the app for review in Add App Option in the facebook audience of your app.After adding, you will have to click on the ad shown on the test app for sending a request.And then hit send for review and facebook will review your app.They will take time and after that you will be served with live ads

Answer (score 0):

What version of Audience Network SdK are you using?  You would need to update to the latest SDK if not.  In addition, you should test it on your Android device.  Please check AdUnitSample and NativeAd Sample apps in the SDK downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, i'm using the latest SDK, and testing it on my Android device.

Answer (score 0):

This issue because of Facebook SDK version changes. Make sure that you have used latest SDK version without minor version code.

I have replace old gradle with this one and it's worked for me

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```